# How to model zero inflated, over dispersed poisson time series?

Tags: time-series, poisson-distribution, autocorrelation, overdispersion, gamlss

I am trying to model weekly disease counts in 25 different regions within 1 country over a ten year period as influenced by temperature.  The data is zero inflated and over dispersed.

I am most familiar with Stata but I don't think that there is any option amongst the `gee`, `xtmixed`, `xtmepoisson` etc. commands that allows me to account for the zero inflation and over dispersion issues as well as the autocorrelation.

I log transformed the incidence data and used a SARIMA model but the residuals are not quite normal.  I think that there are versions of the ARIMA model for integer data like disease counts but I can't find a program for it.

I was also thinking that I could create a hierarchical model with random intercepts for each region and random effects of temperature in each region, while also accounting for the regular seasonal disease cycle.  I believe that I could model this in R using a package like [glmm.admb](http://admb-project.org/examples/r-stuff/glmmadmb) but due to my limited statistical and R knowledge I am not entirely sure how to do use it.  I am mainly confused about accounting for the autocorrelation and seasonal cycle part of the data using a program like this.

Any advice on how to best do this?

Answer (score 4):

You may want to check out `hurdle()` from the `pscl` package in R. It specifies two-component models, one that handles the zero counts and one that handles the positive counts. Check out the `hurdle` help page [here.](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/pscl/html/hurdle.html)

EDIT: I just found [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Problems-using-gamlss-to-model-zero-inflated-and-overdispersed-count-data-quot-the-global-deviance-i-td2239925.html) post in R help that describes the `zeroinf()` function in R (also from the pscl package), as well as `gamlss` and `VGAM` options. However, I don't believe that the `VGAM` options will allow you to take into account non-independent correlation structures.

Another option is the `zinb` command in Stata. Fitting a model using the negative binomial family will account for the overdispersion.

I am not sure if they allow for seasonality adjustments, however.

Comment: +1 In addition, look at the sandwich package which works hand-in-hand with functions in the pscl package to provide appropriate estimation of model covariance matrices that account fot the lack of independence.

Answer (score 3):

Another option for negative binomial regression in R is the excellent MASS package's `glm.nb()` function. UCLA's statistical consulting group has a [pretty clear vignette](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/R/dae/nbreg.htm), which unfortunately does not seem to provide any obvious insights into your autocorrelation issues, but maybe searching these various nb-regression options on R-seek or elsewhere would help?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to SAS 9.2 you could use PROC COUNTREG. It's a fairly new procedure and if you poke around the SAS site you can find out about it in the SAS/ETS(R) 9.2 User's Guide. COUNTREG does count modeling with or without zero inflation, has a "by" clause to split analyses, and allows both categorical and continuous variables.